# Vulkan - do you need a graphics pipeline for each mesh in the scene?

Tags: rust, graphics, vulkan

Do you need a graphics pipeline for each mesh in the scene? or does an object only need a separate pipeline if its going to use a different shader to the others?

Currently learning Vulkan and this would be handy to know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A graphic pipeline can be seen as a pen you use to draw your objects to a canvas (mostly your screen). It describes how objects are drawn, but are not bound to any objects.

So to answer your question, the same pipeline can be used to draw any number of meshes, and yes, if you want different shaders (another pen color) you will need another pipeline.

What is usually done in rendering engines is that objects will store a reference to the graphic pipeline they are using along with shader properties like colors, textures, etc. This is the material of the objects. The material is distinct from the object geometry (the mesh) and any mesh can be rendered with any material. Then, when rendering objects, you can bind the referenced pipeline, and draw your mesh.